# When did Palpatine have children?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, the-rise-of-skywalker, rey

*Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker* re-introduces the emperor, Sheev Palpatine. We learn that

> Rey is his grandchild.

When did he have children?

Are there any hints from canon sources prior to *The Rise of Skywalker* that he might have had children?

Comment: "Are there any hints from canon sources prior to *The Rise of Skywalker* that he might have had children?" Lol, you're so funny! ;)

Comment: There is, as far as I'm aware, no canon indication that Palpatine has ever had a relationship with a woman, let alone had children, let alone had grandchildren, other than in Rise of Skywalker.

Comment: When a daddy Sith Lord and a mummy cloning chamber love each other very much....

Comment: I did rather enjoy Jodie Comer's cameo as said child (or, in fairness, the partner of said child; I don't remember which). Never mind _Killing Eve_, try _Killing Canon_ :)

Comment: Jokes aside, @Valorum, in Legends at least: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Triclops

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings - In the EU, he had a bunch of kids and clones

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings We try not to remember Triclops.

Comment: @DavidW Lol! This is probably more canon-breaking nonsense that Disney made up, but just in case, I wanted to know if there was anything in canon about this.

Comment: No, there was no hint previously. There are, however, also no canon (film) sources that Sheev Palaptine used the bathroom,  took showers (or baths), or was ever younger than middle age. We can, however, make a reasonable assumption that he did, in fact, do those things.

Comment: @KeithMorrison - Palpatine's Senatorial Apartment contained a bathroom, as seen in the Inside the World book. And we see him in his younger days in Darth Plageius

Comment: @KeithMorrison There's a big difference between having a shower and having a child. One is a routine daily activity, while the other is a life altering event. One has zero impact on the plot, while the other is a major plot event.

Comment: @Valorum, that's why I specified film.

Comment: @RichS, Palpatine is a narcissistic sociopath, genocidal dictator, and unapologetic  manipulator of other people. Why do you think him getting a woman pregnant is going to affect him deeply?

Comment: I'm willing to file this one under "never" as rise of skywalker violated just about every concept of star wars available. It's sitting nicely with episodes 1-3 as "never existed" for me. I suggest you do the same.

Comment: @KeithMorrison It's not whether getting a woman pregnant affects him, it's whether the event affects the plot. As I said in my earlier comment, *One has zero impact on the plot, while the other is a major plot event.*

Comment: "When a daddy Sith Lord and a mummy cloning chamber love each other very much.... – Valorum"  hahaha that's funny

Answer (score 18):

[According to comicbook.com](https://comicbook.com/2020/03/05/star-wars-rey-father-failed-palpatine-clone-reveals/):

> Rey’s father is actually [a failed Palpatine clone](https://comicbook.com/starwars/2020/03/03/star-wars-fans-are-livid-over-emperor-palpatine-being-a-clone-in-rise-of-skywalker/) in the [Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker](https://comicbook.com/category/star-wars-episode-ix/) novelization.
>
> ...
>
> In the novelization, Rey is trying to fake out the Emperor during the Sith Ritual on Exegol, she gets a vivid vision of her grandfather’s past. *Return of the Jedi* led the powerful Force user to “thrust his consciousness” into a clone body. But, it would turn out that the “transfer was imperfect” and the Sith present for the transfer decided to get another host ready for Palpatine’s “consciousness.” A certain attempt was describes as a “useless, powerless failure,” who also doubled as a bit of a cosmetic defect as well. **That clone would end up being Rey’s father in the story.**

We also have a quote directly from the film's [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)

> The heretics of the Sith Eternal toiled, splicing genes, bolstering tissue, creating unnatural abominations in the hope that one of these strandcasts would succeed and become a worthy receptacle. The heretics would do anything, risk anything, sacrifice anything, to create a cradle for their god-consciousness.
>
> Nothing worked. But their efforts were not entirely in vain.
>
> **One genetic strandcast lived. Thrived, even. A not-quite-identical clone. His “son.”** But he was a useless, powerless failure. Palpatine could not even bear to look upon such disappointing ordinariness.
>
> **The boy’s only worth would lay in continuing the bloodline through more natural methods.**

Comment: For future reference: http://www.i2ocr.com still needs a bit of proof checking, but it's useful

Answer (score -1):

Maybe he had an off-screen relationship and did not tell anyone about it in order to keep his 'tough, evil guy' persona. This is the best that comes to mind.

Comment: According to the info above, that doesn't appear to be the case